# class org.springframework.web.bind.ServletRequestBindingException 'binderId' is not present

Tags: java, spring, servlets, controller

Can anyone tell me why I am getting this error message while I am trying to download a report (PDF) from a website. Since I am beginner in Spring framework, I am not able to figure it out why this error message has come up. Request to elucidate me. Thanks in advance.

Error message:

**General Error**

Please contact your System Administrator for assistance.

> class org.springframework.web.bind.ServletRequestBindingException
>   Required long parameter 'binderId' is not present

**Show Details**

> org.springframework.web.bind.ServletRequestBindingException: Required
>   long parameter 'binderId' is not present at
>   org.springframework.web.bind.RequestUtils$ParameterParser.validateRequiredParameter(RequestUtils.java:558)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.bind.RequestUtils$ParameterParser.parse(RequestUtils.java:544)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.bind.RequestUtils$LongParser.parseLong(RequestUtils.java:609)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.bind.RequestUtils.getRequiredLongParameter(RequestUtils.java:200)
>   at
>   com.sitescape.team.servlet.forum.ViewFileController.handleRequestAfterValidation(ViewFileController.java:135)
>   at
>   com.sitescape.team.web.servlet.SAbstractController.handleRequestInternal(SAbstractController.java:206)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:44)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:740)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:684)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:394)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:348)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690) at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803) at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
>   at
>   com.sitescape.team.web.servlet.filter.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:56)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:210)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:174)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:151)
>   at
>   org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:200)
>   at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:283)
>   at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:773)
>   at
>   org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:703)
>   at
>   org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:895)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:685)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> org.springframework.web.bind.ServletRequestBindingException: Required
>   long parameter **'binderId' is not present at**

I guess you have a `@RequestParam("binderId")` in your controller parameters, with this config, `binderId` would be required. As a workaround for this problem, either you should pass `binderId` parameter or make the parameter `optional` like this:

`@RequestParam(value = "binderId", required = false)`